# Web service for data syncing between mobile apps

Tags: android, ios, web-services, mobile

I'm looking for a solution to synchronize data between iOS and Android apps.
Maybe exist web-services with iOS and Android libs for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: https://parse.com/products/core The service also has social integration like facebook login, etc.

Answer (score 1):

EnduroSync from [Orando Labs](https://orandolabs.com) is a new product that does exactly what you are asking. There are clients for iOS and Android, with more coming.

Full Disclosure: I work at Orando Labs.

The EnduroSync clients allow you to create object data stores on the local devices. The clients are fairly sophisticated - data is modeled as native objects for each client we support (iOS and Android now, more coming). The clients work offline and online. The data is saved to an sqlite database locally.

As you change objects in your model, the deltas are recorded on the device. At some point, you can 'sync' the object data store. Syncing uses a commit/push/pull process (like git), but this is invisible to you. The sync brings your local copy up to date with whatever is on the server, and sends up any changes you have made. Conflicts are resolved using a timestamp based merge, so newer data is not overwritten by older data.

EnduroSync is an online service, so there is no server setup on your end.

There is also a flexible permission system which lets you share the object data stores in a variety of ways. For instance, most applications will have one or more object data stores for each user, for preferences, notes, tags, etc. You can also share object data stores per app, per user type, and with wild cards, many other ways.

So basically you use our client SDK's to model your data on the device. Modeling is with simple objects in the native programming language of the device. If you sign up for the syncing service, you get the syncing also.